# Java Swing Key Events randomly cutting off

Tags: java, swing, events, keyboard, macos-sierra

I'm making a 2D game in Java. When playing, the controls will randomly lock up, usually within 30 seconds, and the bindings stop reacting to key presses. The controls will occasionally return for short periods. I use the Z, X and arrow keys. Using the arrow keys alone seems to be fine, but the Z and X keys seem to trigger the lock-up.

For controls, I originally used KeyListeners, then a KeyEventDispatcher, and then I tried key bindings. It happens for all of them, although KeyListeners still seem to fire KeyReleased events, just not KeyPressed. Key bindings just stop completely.

The game window is a Canvas within a JPanel within a JFrame. The bindings are set using the panel's input and action maps.

I'm on a mac, and I recently upgraded to macOS Sierra. I had seen this problem occur before upgrading, but after upgrading it got MUCH worse, and the game became unplayable. I have not tested on other operating systems or other macs yet.

I've found a few people on the web who seem to be having the same problem, and someone submitted a bug report:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8167263

But otherwise, I haven't found much about a workaround. My best guess at this point is that it's a bug connected to Sierra, and that either there will be a fix or there is something on my mac that needs to be reconfigured. I'll keep looking. Any advice would be great, as I may have missed an important step. Thanks, everyone!

Here is a compilable example using the WASD keys:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class KeyErrorTest
{
    public KeyErrorTest() {}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        KeyErrorTest keyErrors = new KeyErrorTest();
        keyErrors.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        //create panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setFocusable(true);
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();

        //set up bindings for press and release
        InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();
        //W
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), 1);
        actionMap.put(1, new KeyPresser(KeyEvent.VK_W));
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), 2);
        actionMap.put(2, new KeyReleaser(KeyEvent.VK_W));
        //A
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), 3);
        actionMap.put(3, new KeyPresser(KeyEvent.VK_A));
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), 4);
        actionMap.put(4, new KeyReleaser(KeyEvent.VK_A));
        //S
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), 5);
        actionMap.put(5, new KeyPresser(KeyEvent.VK_S));
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), 6);
        actionMap.put(6, new KeyReleaser(KeyEvent.VK_S));
        //D
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), 7);
        actionMap.put(7, new KeyPresser(KeyEvent.VK_D));
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), 8);
        actionMap.put(8, new KeyReleaser(KeyEvent.VK_D));

        //create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Key Bindings Test");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Press [W], [A], [S], or [D] several times");
        System.out.println("The error tends to occur within 30 seconds");
        System.out.println("The keys will randomly stop registering");
    }

    private class KeyPresser extends AbstractAction
    {
        int key;

        public KeyPresser(int key)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println((char)key+" down");
        }
    }

    private class KeyReleaser extends AbstractAction
    {
        int key;

        public KeyReleaser(int key)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println((char)key+" up");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192166/on-mac-in-java-keypressed-event-doesnt-fire-for-certain-keys

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705742/java-keylistener-no-longer-triggers-keypress-event-after-a-letter-key-is-held-do